# New rails project, rails server and console don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know I'm missing something obvious. I'm using RVM with ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.4. I have a folder called rails_projects that house folders with separate projects. Once of my projects works fine, server and console are great. I created a new project, bundle installed, and everything seems fine except both server and console give the following error (logger is the name of the application):

```
/Users/RobertB/rails_projects/logger/config/application.rb:9:in <top (required)>': Logger is not a module (TypeError)
    from /Users/RobertB/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:inrequire'
    from /Users/RobertB/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/RobertB/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:intap'
    from /Users/RobertB/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in <top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:inrequire'
    from script/rails:6:in `'
```

I'm sure I'm making an idiotic mistake, but I just can't get it to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of your application is conflicting with the name of the Logger class in the Ruby standard library. Use a less generic name for your application and it will work out fine.

Comment: I had an inkling that might've been the problem but was too frustrated to use my brain properly. Thanks!